# ValidateCreate function not called on ValidateAndCreate

Tags: validation, go, buffalo

I'm usign buffalo to build a simple backend to store values.
I have a `Target` struct defined as follow:

```
type Target struct {
    ID           uuid.UUID     `json:"id" db:"id"`
    Name         string        `json:"name" db:"name"`
    Description  string        `json:"description" db:"description"`
    Observations []Observation `json:"values,omitempty" has_many:"observations" order_by:"updated_at desc"`
    CreatedAt    time.Time     `json:"created_at" db:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt    time.Time     `json:"updated_at" db:"updated_at"`
}


// ...


func (t *Target) Validate(tx *pop.Connection) (*validate.Errors, error) {
    return validate.Validate(
        &validators.StringIsPresent{Field: t.Name, Name: "Name"},
        &validators.StringLengthInRange{Field: t.Name, Name: "Name", Min: 2, Max: 15},
    ), nil
}

func (t *Target) ValidateCreate(tx *pop.Connection) (*validate.Errors, error) {
    return t.Validate(tx)
}

func (t *Target) ValidateUpdate(tx *pop.Connection) (*validate.Errors, error) {
    return t.Validate(tx)
}
```

A new `Target` is created using the following action:

```
func TargetAdd(c buffalo.Context) error {
    body, err := io.ReadAll(c.Request().Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Get().Error("Error reading body: %v", err)
        return err
    }
    target := &models.Target{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), target)
    vErr, err := models.DB.ValidateAndCreate(target)
    if err != nil {
        log.Get().Error("entity not valid: %s", err)
        return response.SendGeneralError(c, err)
    }
    if vErr.HasAny() {
        log.Get().Error("entity not valid: %s", vErr)
        return response.SendGeneralError(c, err)
    }
    return response.SendOKResponse(c, target)
}
```

The problem is that the ValidateAndCreate function does not call any of the validation functions defined for the `Target` model, even if it should be so ([link to documentation](https://gobuffalo.io/documentation/database/mutations/#with-validation)).

---

Debugging the issue, I found that in the `validation.go` file, in this function

```
func (m *Model) validateCreate(c *Connection) (*validate.Errors, error) {
    return m.iterateAndValidate(func(model *Model) (*validate.Errors, error) {
        verrs, err := model.validate(c)
        if err != nil {
            return verrs, err
        }
        if x, ok := model.Value.(validateCreateable); ok {
            vs, err := x.ValidateCreate(c)
            if vs != nil {
                verrs.Append(vs)
            }
            if err != nil {
                return verrs, err
            }
        }

        return verrs, err
    })
}
```

the call to `model.Value.(validateCreateable)` seems to return `ok` to `false`.
Can someone please explain me where's the problem and how it's possibile to validate a model? Thanks.

---

**EDIT:**
Changing the import from

```
"github.com/gobuffalo/validate"
"github.com/gobuffalo/validate/validators"
```

to

```
"github.com/gobuffalo/validate/v3"
"github.com/gobuffalo/validate/v3/validators"
```

seems to fix the problem I have